# Fast algorithms in Javascript for shortest path queries in directed unweighted graphs - follow-up

Tags: javascript, algorithm, comparative-review, pathfinding

(See the [previous iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/227519/fast-algorithms-in-javascript-for-shortest-path-queries-in-directed-unweighted-g).)

Now I have reworked my pathfinder program, and I ended up with this:

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="output">

</div>
<script>
function NodeSet() {
 this.array = [];
}

NodeSet.prototype.clear = function() {
 this.array = [];
}

NodeSet.prototype.add = function(node) {
 this.array[node.id] = node;
}

NodeSet.prototype.includes = function(node) {
 return this.array[node.id] !== undefined;
}

NodeSet.prototype.size = function() {
 return this.array.length;
}

function Node(id) {
 this.id = id;
 this.children = [];
 this.parents  = [];
}

Node.prototype.toString = function() {
 return "[Node " + this.id + "]";
}

function nodeEq(nodeA, nodeB) {
 return nodeA.id === nodeB.id;
}

function connect(tail, head) {
 tail.children.push(head);
 head.parents.push(tail);
}

function BuildPath(sourceNode, meetingNode, backwardStack) {
 let path = BidirectionalIterativeDeepeningDepthFirstSearch(sourceNode,
                  meetingNode);
 path.splice(-1, 1);
 path.push(...backwardStack);
 return path;
}

function DepthLimitedSearchForward(node, depth, frontier) {
 if (depth === 0) {
  frontier.add(node);
  return;
 }
 
 node.children.forEach(function(child) {
  DepthLimitedSearchForward(child, depth -  1, frontier);
 });
}

function DepthLimitedSearchBackward(node, depth, backwardStack, frontier) {
 backwardStack.unshift(node);
 
 if (depth === 0) {
  if (frontier.includes(node)) {
   return node;
  }
  
  backwardStack.shift();
  return null;
 }
 
 for (var i = 0; i !== node.parents.length; i++) {
  let parent = node.parents[i];
  let meetingNode = DepthLimitedSearchBackward(parent, depth - 1, backwardStack, frontier);
  
  if (meetingNode !== null) {
   return meetingNode;
  }
 }
 
 backwardStack.shift();
 return null;
}

function BidirectionalIterativeDeepeningDepthFirstSearch(sourceNode, 
               targetNode) {
 if (sourceNode.id === targetNode.id) {
  return [sourceNode];
 }
 
 let frontier = new NodeSet();
 let backwardStack = [];
 let depth = 0;
 
 while (true) {
  DepthLimitedSearchForward(sourceNode, depth, frontier);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   let meetingNode = DepthLimitedSearchBackward(targetNode, 
                        depth + i, 
                     backwardStack, 
               frontier);
  
   if (meetingNode !== null) {
    return BuildPath(sourceNode, 
         meetingNode, 
         backwardStack);
   }
   
   backwardStack = [];
  }
 
  frontier.clear();
  depth++;
 }
}

function DequeNode(elem) {
 this.next = undefined;
 this.elem = elem;
}

function Deque() {
 this.head = undefined;
 this.tail = undefined;
 this.size = 0;
}

Deque.prototype.shift = function() {
 let ret = this.head.elem;
 this.head = this.head.next;
 this.size--;
 return ret;
}

Deque.prototype.push = function(elem) {
 let newNode = new DequeNode(elem);
 
 if (this.head) {
  this.tail.next = newNode;
 } else {
  this.head = newNode;
 }
 
 this.size++;
 this.tail = newNode;
}

Deque.prototype.length = function() {
 return this.size;
}

Deque.prototype.front = function() {
 return this.head.elem;
}

let NULL = "NULL";

function tracebackPath(touchNode, parentsA, parentsB) {
 let path = [];
 let current = touchNode;
 
 while (current != NULL) {
  path.push(current);
  current = parentsA.get(current);
 }
 
 path.reverse();
 
 if (parentsB) {
  current = parentsB.get(touchNode);
 
  while (current != NULL) {
   path.push(current);
   current = parentsB.get(current);
  }
 }
 
 return path;
}

function NodeMap() {
 this.array = [];
 this.size = 0;
}

NodeMap.prototype.put = function(key, value) {
 if (this.array[key.id] === undefined) {
  this.array[key.id] = value;
  this.size++;
 }
}

NodeMap.prototype.get = function(key) {
 return this.array[key.id];
}

NodeMap.prototype.containsKey = function(key) {
 return this.array[key.id] !== undefined;
}

NodeMap.prototype.length = function() {
 return this.size;
}

function BidirectionalBreadthFirstSearch(s, t) {
 let queueA = new Deque();
 let queueB = new Deque();
 
 let parentsA = new NodeMap();
 let parentsB = new NodeMap();
 
 let distanceA = new NodeMap();
 let distanceB = new NodeMap();
 
 queueA.push(s);
 queueB.push(t);
 
 parentsA.put(s, NULL);
 parentsB.put(t, NULL);
 
 distanceA.put(s, 0);
 distanceB.put(t, 0);
 
 let bestCost = 1000 * 1000 * 1000;
 let touchNode = undefined;
 
 while (queueA.length() > 0 && queueB.length() > 0) {
  let distA = distanceA.get(queueA.front());
  let distB = distanceB.get(queueB.front());
  
  if (touchNode && bestCost < distA + distB) {
   return tracebackPath(touchNode,
         parentsA, 
         parentsB); 
  }
  
  if (distanceA.length() < distanceB.length()) {
   let current = queueA.shift();
   
   for (let i = 0; i < current.children.length; i++) {
    let child = current.children[i];
    
    if (!distanceA.containsKey(child)) {
      distanceA.put(child, distanceA.get(current) + 1);
      parentsA.put(child, current);
      queueA.push(child);
      
      if (distanceB.containsKey(child) 
      &&
      bestCost > distanceA.get(child) + distanceB.get(child)) {
      bestCost = distanceA.get(child) + distanceB.get(child);
      touchNode = child;
     }
    }
   }
  } else {
   let current = queueB.shift();
   
   for (let i = 0; i < current.parents.length; i++) {
    let parent = current.parents[i];
    
    if (!distanceB.containsKey(parent)) {
      distanceB.put(parent, distanceB.get(current) + 1);
      parentsB.put(parent, current);
      queueB.push(parent);
      
     if (distanceA.containsKey(parent)
      &&
      bestCost > distanceA.get(parent) + distanceB.get(parent)) {
      bestCost = distanceA.get(parent) + distanceB.get(parent);
      touchNode = parent;
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
  
 return [];
}

function BreadthFirstSearch(source, target) {
 let queue = new Deque();
 let parents = new NodeMap();
 
 queue.push(source);
 parents.put(source, NULL);
 
 while (queue.length() > 0) {
  let current = queue.shift();
  
  if (current.id === target.id) {
   return tracebackPath(current, parents, undefined);
  }
  
  for (let i = 0; i < current.children.length; i++) {
   let child = current.children[i];
   
   if (!parents.containsKey(child)) {
    parents.put(child, current);
    queue.push(child);
   }
  }
 }
 
 return [];
}

function createGraph(nodes, arcs) {    
 let graph = [];
 
 for (var id = 0; id < nodes; id++) {
     graph.push(new Node(id));
    }
    
    for (var i = 0; i < arcs; i++) {
     let tailIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * nodes);
     let headIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * nodes);
     connect(graph[tailIndex], graph[headIndex]);
    }
 
 return graph;
}
 
let outputDiv = document.getElementById("output");

const NODES = 1000000;
const ARCS  = 5000000;
const graph = createGraph(NODES, ARCS);

let sourceIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * NODES);
let targetIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * NODES);

let sourceNode = graph[sourceIndex];
let targetNode = graph[targetIndex];

console.log("Source node: " + sourceNode);
console.log("Target node: " + targetNode);
outputDiv.innerHTML += "Source node: " + sourceNode + "<br>" +
        "Target node: " + targetNode + "<br>";
        
outputDiv.innerHTML += "<br>BIDDFS:";

var startTime = new Date().getMilliseconds();
var path = BidirectionalIterativeDeepeningDepthFirstSearch(sourceNode, 
                 targetNode);
var endTime = new Date().getMilliseconds();
var num = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
 let node = path[i];
 outputDiv.innerHTML += "<br>" + num + ": " + node;
 console.log(num++ + ": " + node);
}

let duration = endTime - startTime;
console.log("Duration: " + duration + " ms.");
outputDiv.innerHTML += "<br>Duration: " + duration + " ms.";
outputDiv.innerHTML += "<br><br>Bidirectional BFS:";

startTime = new Date().getMilliseconds();
var path2 = BidirectionalBreadthFirstSearch(sourceNode, 
           targetNode);
endTime = new Date().getMilliseconds();
duration = endTime - startTime;
num = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < path2.length; i++) {
 let node = path2[i];
 outputDiv.innerHTML += "<br>" + num + ": " + node;
 console.log(num++ + ": " + node);
}

console.log("Duration: " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms.");
outputDiv.innerHTML += "<br>Duration: " + duration + " ms.";
outputDiv.innerHTML += "<br><br>BFS:";

startTime = new Date().getMilliseconds();
var path3 = BreadthFirstSearch(sourceNode, 
          targetNode);
endTime = new Date().getMilliseconds();
duration = endTime - startTime;
num = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < path3.length; i++) {
 let node = path3[i];
 outputDiv.innerHTML += "<br>" + num + ": " + node;
 console.log(num++ + ": " + node);
}

console.log("Duration: " + duration + " ms.");
outputDiv.innerHTML += "<br>Duration: " + duration + " ms.";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Example output**

```
Source node: [Node 437100]
Target node: [Node 368960]

BIDDFS:
1: [Node 437100]
2: [Node 815624]
3: [Node 858313]
4: [Node 506296]
5: [Node 956880]
6: [Node 172071]
7: [Node 406177]
8: [Node 443935]
9: [Node 250512]
10: [Node 368960]
Duration: 5 ms.

Bidirectional BFS:
1: [Node 437100]
2: [Node 815624]
3: [Node 858313]
4: [Node 506296]
5: [Node 956880]
6: [Node 172071]
7: [Node 406177]
8: [Node 443935]
9: [Node 250512]
10: [Node 368960]
Duration: 20 ms.

BFS:
1: [Node 437100]
2: [Node 815624]
3: [Node 966613]
4: [Node 62273]
5: [Node 951283]
6: [Node 238369]
7: [Node 436275]
8: [Node 327303]
9: [Node 818069]
10: [Node 368960]
Duration: 652 ms.
```

**Critique request**

Please tell me anything that comes to mind.

Comment: Is function _BidirectionalIterativeDeepeningDepthFirstSearch_ declared correctly, it seems odd to me?